# persist React logged in user

Tags: reactjs, local-storage

I am able to register, sign in, and sign out a user in my React-Django app. I am setting the user data (username, email, etc.) in local storage on login. However, when I try to go to a protected route (such as "/about"), I am re-directed to "/login", as it seems that React cannot check user state fast enough when it is trying to hit a protected route. When I hit a protected route, I am console.logging the user state just to prove that the state still exists, but is not retrieved fast enough (before render).

When I login then go to the protected "/about" route, my console.logs are:

```
AuthContext state:  {user: null}
AuthContext state:  {user: null}
AuthContext state:  {user: {…}}
AuthContext state:  {user: {…}}
```

So, I need help accessing the user state fast enough, before the protected page renders. Ideas?

Here is my code:

src/context/AuthContext.js:

```
export const AuthContext = createContext()

export const authReducer = (state, action) => {
    switch (action.type){
        case "LOGIN":  
            return { user: action.payload }
        case "LOGOUT": 
            localStorage.removeItem("mysUser")
            return { user: null }
        default: 
        return state
    }   
}

export const AuthContextProvider = ({ children }) =>{
    
    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(authReducer, {
        user: null
    })

    useEffect(() => {
        const user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("mysUser"))
        if (user){
            dispatch({ type: "LOGIN", payload: user })
        }
    }, [])

    console.log("AuthContext state: ", state)
    return (
        <AuthContext.Provider value={{ ...state, dispatch}}>
            { children }
        </AuthContext.Provider>
    )
}
```

src/App.js

```
function App() {

  // auth state
  const { user } = useAuthContext()


  return (
    <div className="App">
      <BrowserRouter>
        <NavbarComponent/>
        <div>

          <Routes>
          
          {/* protected route */}
          <Route
              path="/about"
              element={user ? <About /> : <Navigate to="/login" />}
              exact
            />
            

          {/* non-protected routes */}
          <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />

          <Route path="/signup" element={<Signup />} exact />
          <Route path="/login" element={<Login/>} exact />
        </Routes>
          
        </div>
        <FooterComponent />
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Why not just add a loading state so it has time to get the data?

`const [loggedUser, setLoggedUser] = useState(null)`
`const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true)`
```
useEffect(() => {
  if(user) setLoggedUser(user)
  setLoading(false)
}, [user])
```

and then just swap out `user` for `loggedUser` and map the return in loading

Comment: Nikster- where do I put the loading useEffect hook? and how do I make the components only render after the useEffect finishes? It seems like useEffect runs AFTER render

Answer (score 0):

In your `App` function you could do this

yes the useEffect does run after render, but if you do it this way the link will update if a user becomes available.

Since your custom hook is already triggering after the render happens and not before. You can watch the change with the useEffect and update a state value with the user which will cause a re-render but you wont notice a re-render since you're just swapping components behind the scene.

#### Updated

Here is where the problem lies

A  element changes the current location when it is rendered. It's a component wrapper around useNavigate, and accepts all the same arguments as props.

Since your user hasn't populate the context until after render Navigate fires and redirects you.

VS if you change it to the component `<Login />` itself you wouldn't face that issue. It would direct you to login but would have the `/about`

Play around with the logic a little but removing `Navigate` will solve the problem.

```
import {useState, useEffect} from 'react'; //added

function App() {
  const [currUser, setCurrUser] = useState(null) //added

  // auth state
  const { user } = useAuthContext()

  useEffect(() => { //added
    if(user) {
      setCurrUser(user);
    }
  }, [user]) 
  


  return (
    <div className="App">
      <BrowserRouter>
        <NavbarComponent/>
        <div>

          <Routes>
          
          {/* protected route */}
          {/* changed user to currUser */}
          {/* Removed navigate as that auto fire  */}
          <Route
              path="/about"
              element={currUser ? <About /> : <Login />}
              exact
            />
            

          {/* non-protected routes */}
          <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />

          <Route path="/signup" element={<Signup />} exact />
          <Route path="/login" element={<Login/>} exact />
        </Routes>
          
        </div>
        <FooterComponent />
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Nikster- thanks for sending this over. However, I have tried your suggested changes in App.js, and am still getting the same problem. I am still being re-routed to the login page if I try to go to a protected route, even though there is an existing user. console.logs still the same: ```AuthContext state:  {user: null}
AuthContext.js:30 AuthContext state:  {user: null}
AuthContext.js:30 AuthContext state:  {user: {…}}
AuthContext.js:30 AuthContext state:  {user: {…}}```

Comment: What does your index.js file look like? Are you wrapping `AuthContextProvider`

Comment: <React.StrictMode>
    <AuthContextProvider>
      <App />
    </AuthContextProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>

Comment: Ahh i think I figured out why now. Navigate is auto redirecting your app to login.

A <Navigate> element changes the current location when it is rendered. It's a component wrapper around useNavigate, and accepts all the same arguments as props.

if you do this `element={currUser ? <About /> : <Login />}` should have the same effect unless

You could also just wrap the route. I'll update my code